# Bare branches on schefflera plant

Tags: pruning

My schefflera has leaf stems but not on the bottom 2.5 feet. If I cut it back will it grow leaf stems where it is bare?[image]

Comment: can you add a photo,including showing the pot it's in please?

Answer (score 1):

These plants bud readily from old growth and if they are cut back leaf stems will grow from various points on the older woodier stem but...

- if light levels are low then you might only get one new bud
- if the plant is stressed due to overwatering or pests you are unlikely to get more than one bud

If you are going to cut it back give it lots of light and a light touch of 20-20-20 fertilizer before.